# Error compiling kernel module, fatal error: linux/modversions.h: File or directory not found

Tags: c, linux, module, kernel

i'm trying to compile a simple test kernel module but gcc drop me this error:

```
fatal error: linux/modversions.h: file or directory not found
```

but in 
/usr/src contains the symlink to the linux souce indeed

```
ls -l /usr/scr/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 apr 26 13:31 fglrx-14.9+ga14.201
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       39 lug 11 13:36 linux -> /home/nhoya/Scaricati/linux-source-3.16
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 lug 10 17:49 linux-config-3.16
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 lug 10 15:57 linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 apr 26 22:24 linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       23 giu 24  2012 linux-kbuild-3.2 -> ../lib/linux-kbuild-3.2
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 81869308 mag 24 20:24 linux-source-3.16.tar.xz
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root     4096 giu  7 23:31 virtualbox-4.3.18
```

and

```
locate modversions.h
/home/nhoya/Scaricati/linux-source-3.16/include/config/modversions.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64/include/config/modversions.h
```

So, i really don't understand the problem... this is the module source

```
#define __KERNEL__
#define MODULE

#include <linux/modversions.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

#include <linux/tty.h>


int init_mod()
{
  console_print("test\n");

  return 0;
}


void cleanup_mod()
{
  console_print("fine test\n");
}
```

Comment: How are you invoking the compiler? Are you following [the documented procedure](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x181.html)?

Comment: gcc -c -Wall -nostdinc -I /usr/src/linux/include/ foo.c

Comment: Don't do that. Read and follow the documentation. Use the ready-made makefile for kernel modules.

Comment: ok, solved in my lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64 the direcory build didn't exist so i used the modules from 3.2.0-4-amd64/  not it works. But how to have for 3.16? btw  Ty!

Comment: Oooops, i missed the headers for 3.16 :/ Problem solved!